# "Bad system call: 12" crashes when using a static framework on iOS with IPA-deployment (not Xcode run)

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, frameworks, llvm

I'm working with a static framework I've created (built with the help of Karl Stenerud's [iOS-Universal-Framework](https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework) toolchain), which I intend to distribute. A static framework's a bit more convenient than simply using a static lib + headers - I like the ability to just drop a framework in and begin using it immediately, instead of needing to do things like set up appropriate header search paths.

However, I'm seeing some downright bizarre behaviour. Several test/sample apps that I have built with the framework are crashing with either "*Bad system call: 12*" or "*Job appears to have crashed: Illegal instruction: 4*" when run on iOS devices to which the app has been deployed *via an ipa*.

The code itself is fine. The crash does not occur when a static library is used instead of a framework. It also doesn't crash if the app is deployed via the debugger in Xcode, even when the Release build configuration is used.

The crash *only* happens when deployed via an ipa, and when the library is linked as a static framework.

Interestingly, the corresponding crash log's stack trace entries leading up to the crash (which is EXC_CRASH or EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION) cannot be symbolicated.

In one instance, I was able to track the crash down to the point where a static C function is called. By removing the "static" keyword on a whim, I was able to stop the crash happening.

Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to be the silver bullet - I'm also seeing a crash on a non-static C function call.

But in all cases, the crash occurs when a C function is being called.

So, my question is this: Has anyone else seen this before? Any theories? Is this likely to be an LLVM bug? Some magical compiler/linker flag I'm missing?  Have Apple deliberately only half-supported static frameworks because there are issues? Do I just need to abandon my plan to distribute a framework, instead of a static library and assorted detritus?

Many thanks in advance,

Michael

Answer (score 1):

The problem would appear to be related to static recursive functions!

Quoting Karl Stenerud, who figured it out:

> It fails if you have a static recursive function:
>
> ```
> @implementation Fibonacci
>
> static int internalFibonacci(int value)
> {
>     if(value <= 1)
>     {
>         return value;
>     }
>     return internalFibonacci(value - 1) + internalFibonacci(value - 2);
> }
>
> + (int) fibonacci:(int) value
> {
>     return internalFibonacci(value);
> }
>
> @end
> ```
>
> If you call [Fibonacci fibonacci:] it will fail with "Bad system call: 12".
>
> If you remove "static" from internalFibonacci(), it works perfectly.

Comment: Hi Michael,
I'm facing the very same issue, i don't have this sort of recursive C function. Have you understand what's the real issue?

Answer (score 0):

I already came across similar issues. I develop iOS frameworks for a company and we provide those framework to clients who develop their own applications or framework above ours.

When we perform testing in our own, everything seems to work fine and applications just work perfectly. But as soon as applications/frameworks are built using different Xcode/Compiler version, there is no guarantee that everything will work just as expected.
The crashes that clients reported to us do always mention a bad code execution or bad arm instruction (the same as you got).

We searched a lot around the Apple developer forums but there few mentions to this issue, and Apple doesn't really seem to want to communicate about that.

From my experience, here are some clues that may perhaps help you:

- Build your framework on Xcode 4.1, iOS SDK 4.3 and Apple LLVM 2.1
- on OS X Lion, Xcode 4.3 you can build using LLVM GCC and make sure to disable THUMB support in your build settings.

You can try the last solution. I have made many tests with all possible compilers on OS X Lion, and so far, this configuration appears to be stable.
I haven't tested yet the new Xcode 4.3.2 and iOS SDK 5.1. I'll let you know as soon as I do it.

Regards,

Hichem

Comment: Cheers Hichem! I forgot to mention that we seem to have discovered at least *one* cause - see my answer. Karl has reported it to the LLVM team, I think, who'll probably be more responsive.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for this clue. I'll check if I have any recursive functions around the piece of code that causes the crash. I fear however that there are more reasons for this to happen and we'll need to wait for the LLVM team to provide a proper fix. cheers.